# How to run TC in headless (Poltergeist) mode using Ruby, Rspec, Capybara and Selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

The problem is that I've tried a lot of variants to declare Capybara Poltergeist driver. But alway get some problems.

For instance, when I declare driver as following:

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new({
        js_errors: true,
        inspector: true,
        phantomjs_options: ['--load-images=no', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes'],
        timeout: 120
    })
```

TC are ran in FF browser instead of poltergeist(((

or, if I declare driver as following:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

I see such error:
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require': cannot load such file -- support/controllers_helpers (LoadError).

Also I need to use Selenium and Capybara methods, therefore I declared following variable to be able to use selenium methods:
@driver = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser

So, the question is how to declare Capybara headless driver (with debugging opportunity if possible) with the opportunity to use Selenium methods (my @driver variable)? `enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the poltergeist driver and use selenium methods -- The selenium specific methods are only available when using the selenium driver.

For your issue of declaring a driver:  Declaring/Configuring a driver (using Capybara.register_driver) just names the driver - then you still have to specify to use it (via the name you specified in register_driver) with Capybara.default_driver, current_driver, or javascript_driver - depending on exactly what you're setting up.

I think you really need to think through what you're trying to do and then explain it to us in more detail.